# x86 32 intel - MOV vs LEA with pointers

Tags: x86

I randomly remembered I  specifically used LA (which I'm guessing is the MIPS equivalent of LEA) when trying to accessing variables on the stack in a prior MIPS assembly course. However, in x86 32 intel , I realized I primarily use mov to access variables in the stack. I understand that LEA loads an address, and stores the address in a register, and then by dereferenced to change to obtain the value that was at that address.

I see that eax is will be equal to esp+4 dereferenced in both scenarios. What are the benefits of using one method over the other, in this scenario ? 
I wrote this code to obtain the arguments of the function by the way
I'm curious bc my professor in my MIPS course told us to avoid using mov I don't remember at all why he would do so.

```
mov $eax [$esp+4]
```

vs

```
lea $eax [$esp+4]
mov $eax [$eax]
```

Comment: The first is equivalent to the MIPS `lw $t0, 4($sp)`. The second is equivalent to `addiu $t0, $sp, 4` followed by `lw $t0, 0($t0)`.

Comment: What syntax is this?  It's not normal Intel syntax for any assembler I'm familiar with (NASM/YASM, FASM, MASM, GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix`), nor is it AT&T or Plan9/Go.  It looks like you used MIPS `$reg` decorations and forgot the commas between operands.  Intel syntax doesn't decorate register names; AT&T decorates with `%`.  Some MIPS assemblers allow omitting commas, but x86 assemblers don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MIPS `la` is the same as x86 `mov reg, imm32`: It's a pseudo-instruction for putting address constants into registers.  It *only* works for actual constants, unlike LEA which can use any addressing mode.

[MIPS](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) doesn't have a real `move` instruction; `move $t1, $t0` is a pseudo-op for
`or  $t1, $zero, $t0`, i.e. it does  `$t1 = 0 | $t0 = $t0`.  If you need to copy a register, you might as well write it as `move` instead of `addu` or `or` with the zero register.  (But usually in MIPS you can avoid copying registers, because instructions have a separate destination, unlike x86 where the `add` instruction does `dst += src` instead of `dst = src1 + src2`.)

x86 addressing modes can use 32-bit constants directly, and there are far fewer registers available.  It often makes sense to use an address directly instead of putting it into a register first.  e.g. `add eax, [my_array + ecx*4]`.  See [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes).

MIPS only has one addressing mode: register + 16-bit immediate.  For small addresses (in the low 16 bits of address space), you can use them directly, e.g.  `ls $t0,  my_static_variable($zero)`   or `lw $t0, my_array($t1)`.  (But of course you don't have scaled indexes, so you have to `addui $t1, $t1, 4` to index the next element).